# I posted a new answer by editing my existing answer

Tags: bug, specific-answer

I'm not entirely sure how I managed this, but as I was editing my [existing answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67017474/2005939) I got a notification that [the question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67017330/on-hover-show-links/67017553) just got another answer. I'm almost positive I didn't press any buttons. Upon saving my edit I found out that my edit had become an entirely [new answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67017553/2005939) and my old answer was untouched.

I deleted my "new" answer and edited my old answer again. Unfortunately, I'm not sure what caused this. I was working in a single tab and the edit consisted of an added sentence and some comments in the snippet editor.

The browser I used was Microsoft Edge 89.0.774.63 on Windows 10 1909.

[image]

Comment: You're a wizard, thordarson.

Comment: If this is the day I find out I have telekinetic powers, I'm all for it!

Comment: Possibly related (from MSE): [Randomly created answer draft after edit](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/202260)

Comment: Been there! :-)

Comment: This has happened to me also more than once. Never knew if it was user error or a bug. I think it's a bug but not sure how to replicate it